# REST API design with HMAC: How to handle security on first user registration

Tags: php, security, rest, hmac

I would to implement a secure REST web service for a mobile app (using PHP).
The idea is to avoid the complexity of OAuth, so I've decided to use the HMAC approach.
I've read some articles [like this](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/).

Basically what I need to do is this:

- [**CLIENT**] Before making an API request combine a bunch of data it will send (ie. the url params) and hash it with the private key assigned from the server (**HASHED_KEY**). This data is sent along with some sort of id/key which allows the server to identify who is the sender (ie. client id,or some sort of public id of the user, it does not matter, we'll call it **USER_IDENTIFIER**). So at the end we have a request URL with **HASH_KEY**+**USER_IDENTIFIER** (ie. mywebservice/users/list?hash=[**HASH_KEY**]&key=[**USER_IDENTIFIER**]).
- [**SERVER**] Server receive this request, take (using **USER_IDENTIFIER**) the private key assigned to the user and HASH the same data hashed by client. If both hash keys (generated from client and generated from server) matches request can be trusted and executed.

(We can also avoid replay attacks and add some other security levels but that's the core).

My question is this:

My APIs should also allow user registration.
So there will be a call called /*register_user* where client should send at least desired username and password.
After that, server should reply with the private key (HASHED_KEY) client will use to encrypt all other requests.
So basically there is a flaw: this first communication is not secure.
How can I handle this?

My idea is to provide a private key for anonymous calls both on server and client which is used to encrypt data when I don't know yet the user identity. It will be used to secure both username+password while making registration call.
Is it okay? Any other solution?

Comment: "*So basically there is a flaw: this first communication is not secure.*" Secure in what way ? For peeking ? Use SSL

Comment: During this first communication server will send to the client the private key used during all other sessions requests. If anyone can intercept this first handshake all other security mechanism is compromised.

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, use SSL. In a web context, HTTPS.

Comment: Okay thanks, just another question: what's the point of making these other security things if I can simply encrypt all data behind anSSL connection?

Comment: If all you are interested in is protecting from peeking to requests between your client(s) and server, if you use SSL your homemade HMAC becomes redundant, from my point of view. If you also need authorization for your clients, although you find OAuth complex, you may want to take a second look at it, because this is for what it was designed in the first place.

Comment: OAuth need not be difficult. I have seen that article cited here on SO a couple of times now, and the guy end up designing OAuth1 himself with all the possibilities of doing it wrong. "Avoid the complexities of OAuth" ... and introduce them yourself instead? Why? OAuth1 may be complex on the crypto side, but OAuth2 is definitively not. See http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/api-authentication-considerations-and.html for a different point of view than the article you have cited.